# flv video streaming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want to play a flv video from a remote server i search on net but i donot find any solution but their are some apps in app store which can play flv videos. Any idea how to stream flv videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Playing .flv files on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231535/playing-flv-files-on-iphone) for a good discussion and useful ideas.

Answer (score 1):

IPhone,iPad doesn't  support flash content.
Check : https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/
it is possible to create a Server Side encoding  a FLV video using custom code and then feed the flv file into that.

Answer (score 0):

it may be possible by using libav (aka ffmpeg) library.you can decode the .flv file into some other formate and use it.