# How to play flv video in ios webview?

Tags: video, uiwebview, ios10, wkwebview, flv

I have real time flv format video on my web page. I want to use webview to load this page in my ios app. But for flv is not a HTML5 support video format, so it cannot played directly without flash. I also try to use flv.js, flv.js is written in pure JavaScript without Flash. Then video can play in web page without flash, but still cannot paly in my app. In my app, I used WKwebview.

Comment: I finally refer to ijkplayer to play the video, not the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**FLV.JS**](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) readme for [**livestreaming**](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/blob/master/docs/livestream.md) (see: *[**Compatibility**](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/blob/master/docs/livestream.md#compatibility)* at bottom) :

(updated March 17 2017)

> Due to IO restrictions, flv.js can support HTTP FLV live stream on
>   Chrome 43+, FireFox 42+ and Edge 15.15048+ for now.
>
> HTTP FLV live stream relies on stream IO, which has been introduced in
>   [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) and [stream](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) spec. but FetchStreamLoader only works well on a few
>   browsers for now:
>
> - Safari: fetch has not been supported on current version 10, but available in [Safari Technology
>     Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

This may be what is affecting the ability to playback FLV video on iOS via **WKwebview**. 
It seems iOS SDK (eg: Swift) itself [can use the *fetch* protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content//releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation-v10.10/index.html#10_10NSXPC) but here in your project you're relying only on the WebKit browser renderer (which may not yet support this feature?).

Answer (score 1):

You can go see ability HTML5 Supprt Video Type https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: I only have the real time flv format stream and rtmp stream.

Comment: see in comment this header too you post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231535/playing-flv-files-on-iphone